# 400 Bad Request - $http.post to Flask backend

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am using angularjs to post to my Flask backend using the ng-change directive and $http.post, but am getting a 400 Bad Request whenever I enter text into the input.

Here is my angularjs code:

```
var strategyMapApp = angular.module('strategyMapApp', ['textAngular'])
.config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[').endSymbol(']}');
});

strategyMapApp.controller('StrategyMapCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.change = function(mapping){
        $http.post('/strategymap',mapping);
    };

    $scope.textAngularOpts = {};
});
```

Here is the relevant code from my html file:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="strategyMapApp">
   <div class="pull-right"><button></button></div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Sector</th>
            <th>Company Industry</th>
            <th>Economic Cycle Position</th>
            <th>Macro Strategy</th>
            <th>Tactical Strategy</th>
            <th>Guidance</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-controller="StrategyMapCtrl" 
             ng-init="mapping.ticker='{{ overview[0].ticker}}'">
             <tr>
                <td>{{ overview[0].company_sector }}</td>
                <td>{{ overview[0].company_industry }}</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="mapping.cycle_position"
                    ng-change="change(mapping)"
                    placeholder="{{ mapping.cycle_position }}"/></td>
                 <td><input type="text" ng-model="mapping.macro_strategy"
                     ng-change="change(mapping)"/></td>
                 <td><input type="text" ng-model="mapping.tactical_strategy"
                     ng-change="change(mapping)"/></td>
                 <td><input type="text" ng-model="mapping.guidance"
                     ng-change="change(mapping)"/></td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and lastly, my Flask function for handling the POST request:

```
@app.route('/strategymap', methods=['GET','POST'])
def strategymap():
    #form = TickerForm(request.form)
    #ticker = Ticker()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        print data
        ticker = data['ticker']
        mapping = Ticker.objects.get(ticker=ticker)
        print mapping
        if mapping:
            mapping.cycle_position = data['cycle_position'] if 
               'cycle_position' in data.keys() 
               else mapping.cycle_position
            mapping.macro_strategy = data['macro_strategy'] if 
               'macro_strategy' in data.keys() 
               else mapping.macro_strategy
            mapping.tactical_strategy = data['tactical_strategy'] if
               'tactical_strategy' in data.keys() 
               else mapping.tactical_strategy
            mapping.save()
        else:
            mapping = Ticker(ticker=data['ticker'],
                      cycle_position=data['cycle_position'],
                      macro_strategy=data['macro_strategy'],
                      tactical_strategy=data['tactical_strategy'])
                      .save()
```

So, whenever I type a value into the text inputs, angular is supposed to post the updated model to Flask, but I am getting a 400 Bad Request. I have tried data = request.json & data = request.data as well, to no avail.

Also, in case there is any confusion, the curly braces are from the Jinja2 template and the '{[' and '}]' are the symbols for angularjs.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit - adding the csrf_token from Flask/Jinja2 fixed the problem, updated html/angular code below:

```
<tbody  ng-controller="StrategyMapCtrl" ng-init="mapping.ticker='{{ overview[0].ticker}}'">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" value="{{ nonwtf_csrf_token() }}" id="csrftoken"/></td>
        <td>{{ overview[0].company_sector }}</td>
        <td>{{ overview[0].company_industry }}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="mapping.cycle_position"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="mapping.macro_strategy"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="mapping.tactical_strategy"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="mapping.guidance"/></td>
        <td><button class="btn-primary" ng-click="change(mapping)">Save Mapping</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

strategyMapApp.controller('StrategyMapCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    var csrftoken = document.getElementById('csrftoken').value;
    $scope.change = function(mapping){
        alert(csrftoken);
        mapping.nonwtf_csrf_token = csrftoken;
        alert(JSON.stringify(mapping));
        $http.post('/strategymap',mapping);
    };

    $scope.textAngularOpts = {};
});
```

Comment: I suggest taking Angular out of the equation. Using the network tab in your browser's debug console, it should be possible to see the request getting made. Here is where you can veryify that that request from the UI at least looks correct. You can then use a browser add on (like Postman for Chrome) to manipulate the request until it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Here is the request being made (for example): {"ticker":"PSEC","cycle_position":"Ea","macro_strategy":"In"}. The request works using POSTMan, just not from Angular for some reason

Comment: Well the problem is the 400 bad request is coming from flask so there must be some difference in the request coming from Angular vs the request from POSTMan, beyond the body double check that the HTTP method/verb is the same and the headers are the same.

Comment: I edited your code to make it not scroll horizontally. I am not familiar with Flask, so I am not sure the line breaks in the if statements are correct. If you feel there is an error in the editing, please feel free to correct it.

Comment: Just an update, I had to pass the csrf_token from Flask/Jinja2 within my JSON object that is being posted in order for Flask to accept the request and not give a 400 Bad Request error. I'll add my updated html & angular code, hope this helps someone!